# .NET Maui: ListView reselect Selected Item

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have .NET Maui app in which I display a ListView of ViewCells. When I select an ListView Item it will navigate to a different Page, when I navigate back from that page I either want to unselect the selected Item or I want it so that when I click the selected Item again, to refire that set event

XAML:

```
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey}">
              ...
      </ListView>
```

View Model:

```
        private Key _selectedKey;
        public Key SelectedKey
        {
            get => _selectedKey;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedKey, value);

                if (value != null && Shell.Current.IsLoaded) 
                {
                   SetProperty(ref _selectedKey, null);

                   Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EditKeyPage)}?Id={value.Id}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: set `SelectedKey` to `null` before you navigate

Comment: I thought of that too but it still does not work with following Implementation: 

                if (value != null && Shell.Current.IsLoaded)
                {
                    _selectedKey = null;
                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EditKeyPage)}?Id={value.Id}");
                }

Comment: You need to set the public property, not the private field

Comment: I tried that too :/ weird right?

Comment: `SelectedKey` needs to be observable

Comment: How would I go about making it observable? When I try to do "private ObservableObject<Key> _selectedKey;" 

I get The non-generic type-or-method 'ObservableObject' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty

Comment: or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject if you need more control over the setter

Comment: Now I get the error The type 'KeysViewModel' already contains a definition for 'SelectedKey' as the ObservableObject gets created automatically. How would I still have control over the  setter and navigate my users? I didn't find anything in the docs

Comment: What in the world are you doing with that code? You make the sourcegen generate the observable property for you, then you redefine it wrong? That won't even compile, you need to learn basic C# here.

Comment: If you want to write your own setter, use the 2nd link

Comment: I updated the question, but it still doesn't work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your VM inherit ObservableObject?

Comment: Yes my ViewModel does.

Comment: I would expect that to work (it does in Xamarin).  My MAUI env is borked at the moment so I can't verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `SelectedModel` to `null` after you navigating to another page.

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
        private Key _selectedModel;
        public  Key SelectedModel
        {
            get { return _selectedModel; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedModel, value);

                if (SelectedModel != null)
                {  
                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailPage));
                    
                    // set the SelectedItem to null here
                    SelectedModel = null;
                }

            }
        }
```

I achieved this function on my side, you can refer to the whole code of my viewmodel:

```
 public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Rayon> Sections { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Rayon>();

        private Rayon _selectedModel;
        public Rayon SelectedModel
        {
            get { return _selectedModel; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedModel, value);

                if (SelectedModel != null)
                {

                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailPage));

                    SelectedModel = null;
                }

            }
        }

        public MyViewModel() {
            Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_1",Price=100.0});
            Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_2", Price = 100.0 });
            Sections.Add(new Rayon { SectionName= "section_3", Price = 100.0 });
    
        }
    
        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

**Note:**

Remember to set the `Mode` to `TwoWay`.

Usage example:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" HasUnevenRows="True" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel,Mode=TwoWay}"
              >

              <!--  other code -->
     </ListView>
```

Comment: Does not work with mine, weird right?

Comment: I did a test, and it works on my side.  Could you please more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Remember to set the `Mode` to `TwoWay` while binding  the Selected Item for `SelectedItem`. For example, `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey,Mode=TwoWay}">`

Comment: Hi @bananajoey88, please check my updated answer.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much